# Powershell Code with No Errors not running

Tags: powershell

```
Invoke-Command -cn (Get-Content C:\Users\Administration\Documents\MyText.txt) -scriptblock {Start-Process -FilePath "MyProg.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files\ThisFolder\ThatFolder" -ArgumentList "-1", "-2", "-3"}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what. Anyone seeing something I'm missing?

Comment: Does your `-ComputerName` argument actually have computers to run against?  I'd suggest using `Get-Content C:\CNs.txt | ? { Test-Connection $_ } | etc`

Comment: Well Currently, it only has the computer that the code is running on. It should still work though right?

Comment: It should, assuming the process isn't just launching then closing.  I forgot to mention `-Quiet` on `Test-Connection` so it only returns true/false.  Something I'd suggest trying, instead of `Start-Process` is `& 'C:\path\MyProg.exe' -1 -2 -3`

Comment: Is WinRM enabled, running, and configured to accept requests on the machine(s) in your list?

Comment: My thought was there should be an error if that occurs @ZachAlexander

Comment: @TheIncorrigible You're right, there should be. It's actually more likely that the script is succeeding and starting the program as intended. When you try to launch a process remotely (at least when I try), the process starts but the GUI is disabled. OP should check to see if the process is currently open in the task manager on the remote computer.

Comment: I checked all of this again today, and again Code runs just fine with no errors, but the remote computer gets nothing. The Process isn't running in Task Manager either.

Answer (score 0):

The process is ending after your session on the remote system is closed. When i run the following test, notepad will run for 5 seconds on the remote computer, then close:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock {start-process notepad.exe;Start-Sleep -Seconds 5}
```

If myprog.exe closes on it's own use the -Wait switch to wait for the process to close on it's own. You could also use New-PSSession to keep a session open until you are done then use Remove-PSSession to end the session and have the remote process end.